# Can I use both anchor id and a normal link in a wordpress url?

Tags: html, wordpress, anchor

Can I use both anchor id and a normal link in a wordpress url?

I have a hompage that is clicktrough, I also have some articles that are on separate pages, my menu works with ancor ids, Is it possible to have the menu working on the non clickthrouh pages?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!! When asking questions related to debugging, please post the relevant codes along with a brief description of your issue on your question. Please refer to this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask a question in SO.